# TELNET: Pasting a carriage return into the console

Tags: telnet

I want to issue then following requests to a telnet session:

```
telnet www.example.com 80

GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
```

Telnet doesn't seem to recognise the '\r\n' as a carriage return and just sends the lot on to the remote host. What should I put in place of '\r\n' to render a carriage return in the telnet terminal. It does work when I paste the following into the terminal:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: close
```

followed by two presses of the RETURN key. Is there a hex code I can send to telnet i.e. \0x01 or something like that?

Can I change the options of the TELNET shell to show what I pasted also? I can't find a way to do SET LOCALECHO since I'm opening the TELNET shell and connecting at the same time.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

/r/n is a perfectly acceptable carriage return line feed character for ANSI, which is what most telnet clients communicate in. Are you applying the @ sign in front of your string?

ie:

```
@"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

If you are trying to type in /r/n and pasting that input in raw, then the telnet component will often assume you wanted the characters sent as they are type(not as new lines) and do so accordingly.